# Magento 2 wrong locale in store views (wrong translation)

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have next problem.
I have 2 websites (German and Austria).
Websites have stores (German store and Austria store).
Each store have 2 store views (`German-DE`, `German-EN`, `Austria-DE`, `Austria-EN`).
German store and it's store view `German-DE` is the default store and store view.

Now to the problem. Generally I need to have next translations: 
`Germany-DE - Germany language`;
`Germany-EN - English language`;
`Austria-DE - Germany language`;
`Austria-EN - English language`;

In admin panel i made settings for Locale(`Stores > Configuration > General >`): all English language store views have `en_US` locale and all Germany language store views have `de_DE` locale.

http://joxi.ru/L21PjnVT8nvPJm

But, in Germany store all store views have right translation, but in Austria  translation do not work... Generally Austria store have default store view `Austria-EN` and all store views have english translation. When I switch default store view to Austria-DE, all Austria store views will translate to German. I try to get locale on frontend in some controller using `Magento\Framework\Translate`

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Translate $translate
)
{
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->translate = $translate;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    var_dump($this->translate->getLocale());
    die;

    return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
}
```

and in Austria-DE I get `en_US` when in locale of this store view is set `de_DE`.
Please help me to figure it out what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE
```

Possibly the non default stores didn't get it deployed.